# Bluetooth: can't find default controller

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth

I can't get `bluetoothctl` or `hciconfig` to display anything about my bluetooth controller, or otherwise get my computer to recognize nearby bluetooth devices. When I enter `power on` in `bluetoothctl`, it displays

```
No default controller available.
```

The commands `hcitool scan` and `hciconfig hci0 up` similarly fail to find anything.

Here is some information about my system:

- Kernel

  ```
  uname -a
  Linux localhost 4.0.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 29 12:00:26 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- PCI devices

  ```
  lspci -k

  02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
      DeviceName: Roma Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
      Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
      Kernel driver in use: rt2860
      Kernel modules: rt2800pci, rt3290sta

  02:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
      Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
  ```
- Kernel modules

  ```
  lsmod | grep -i bluetooth

  bluetooth             438272  6 bnep,btusb
  rfkill                 24576  6 cfg80211,hp_wmi,bluetooth
  crc16                  16384  2 ext4,bluetooth
  ```
- Bluetooth-related log messages

  ```
  dmesg | grep -i bluetooth

  [   89.576936] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
  [   89.576970] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
  [   89.576977] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
  [   89.576982] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
  [   89.576991] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
  [   89.587071] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
  [   89.587082] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
  [   89.587094] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
  ```
- Device FS:

  ```
  ls /dev | grep hci

  vhci
  ```

Note that there are several mentions of the WiFi/Bluetooth controller in the system log:

- Searching for the RT3290 gives repeated error messages like

  ```
  dmesg | grep rt3290 

  RT3290_AsicTxAlcGetAutoAgcOffset: Incorrect desired TSSI or current TSSI
  ```
- Searching for "RT28xx" gives

  ```
  dmesg | grep rt28 gives:

  [    9.810624] register rt2860
  [   16.610829] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
  ```

Comment: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1355096)  I don't know if it will ever see support under a linux kernel, it seems to be up to the manufacturer

Comment: Does this help, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/589128/3285

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that you card is not hard or soft blocked (which isn't related to linux):

   - Check that you turned on bluetooth in your bios
   - Check if you have a hardware key for turning off bluetooth (sometimes called "fly mode" or "offline mode")
2. Check that you installed the rt3290 driver. Currently it isn't in the kernel modules (if this hasn't changed)

   - you could search it with `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name "ralink*" | less` or with `modinfo rt3290`
   - if you got `modinfo: ERROR: Module rt3290 not found.` you should install it
   - samples installation guide for ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/924632/rt3290-wifi-not-listing-connections-in-ubuntu-gnome-16-04

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question on AskUbuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778615/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04), this card seems to require the [`rtbth` driver](https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms) for Bluetooth support.

The fact that your Bluetooth adapter appears in `lspci` listing indicates it's a PCI(e)-based adapter, not an USB-based one. And since `lspci -k` cannot identify a driver in use for the Bluetooth function of the adapter, it strongly suggests the correct Bluetooth hardware driver is not loaded right now.

The only Bluetooth hardware driver I can identify in your `lsmod | grep -i bluetooth` is `btusb`, which only covers USB-based Bluetooth adapters. The modules `bnep`, `bluetooth` etc. are generic Bluetooth protocol drivers, but you'll also need the correct hardware driver for your Bluetooth adapter.