# Bluetoothctl: No default controller available

Tags: debian, bluetooth, bluez

When I run `bluetoothctl` I get an error,

```
$ bluetoothctl scan on
No default controller available
```

But the kernel shows the device is loaded,

```
bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-19-0-1.sfi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is install `rfkill` and unblock bluetooth:

```
sudo apt install rfkill
```

Then

```
$ sudo rfkill 
ID TYPE      DEVICE                   SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth tpacpi_bluetooth_sw   blocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0                unblocked unblocked
```

You can see id `0` is blocked,

```
$ sudo rfkill unblock 0
```

If you're still having errors checkout [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169931/328)